# Why didn't Gandalf prevent or lessen Saruman’s damage to the Shire?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-return-of-the-king

In the chapter "Many Partings" the hobbits and Gandalf meet Saruman and Grima on the road. Saruman's intentions are pretty obvious; he even threatens the party:

> Well, it will serve you right when you come home, if you find things
> less good in the Southfarthing than you would like. Long
> may your land be short of leaf!’

Gandalf clearly knows what is up:

> I fancy he could do some mischief still in a small mean way

Saruman is a Maia and still has powers beyond mortals (his voice). It seems out of character that Gandalf did not intervene to stop another Maia, even without using his magical powers or at least warning the Hobbits so that they could take him prisoner and, conveniently, take him to Rivendell where they were going anyway.

There are many literary reasons of why the events leading up to the Scouring of the Shire are there in the story but I struggle to find an in-universe reason of why Gandalf did not try to stop Saruman.

Edit: while there are many reasons Gandalf would not have intervened directly, I have not seen a satisfactory reason of why he could not have at least urged the Hobbits to go directly to The Shire instead of going to Rivendell.

Comment: Aside from the answer below, Gandalf also knew they could handle it, and the Scouring was going on even before they ran into Saruman on the road.

Comment: @Shamshiel Personally, I think that this is the real reason, both in-story and literary.  Gandalf was not there to intervene in things that mortals could handle themselves, and the mortals needed to learn that they could challenge and defeat evil on their own.

Comment: He could have just told them to got the Shire directly instead of Rivendell. And yes, they can handle it but what about the rest of the Hobbits that could not handle it? Are they are supposed to wait patiently until the heroes finish their vacation in Rivendell?

Comment: Having Gandalf just whoop Saruman would kind of defeat the general theme Tolkien has set that even when the good guys win, some damage is permanent.

Comment: That is a literary reason but given the characters and the description of them on previous chapters I don't think Gandalf would have left the Hobbits of the Shire suffer just to make a point

Comment: The wording of this question incorrectly implies that “The Scouring” in the chapter title is the damage done by Saruman. The scouring was Frodo et al. *cleaning out* Saruman and his influence. I’ve now twice suggested an edit to fix it, but it keeps getting rejected.

Comment: @RLH - Lol. I was trying to make this precise edit, but blocked by your edit

Comment: It appears to have happened quickly, in a few months of time (possibly as soon as the Dunedain rangers left that region to help Aragorn) so how could Gandalf have prevented it, since he was well-busy elsewhere with the major events in the south. He could have helped the hobbits reclaim the Shire but didn't think they would need his help, which proves correct.

Comment: Could have at least prevented the Hobbits from going to Rivendell

Comment: @Amarth: It began around the time Frodo left the Shire, all the hobbits are noting that a lot of Men have been about and strange things are happening. We find out later those were Saruman’s agents

Comment: @Shamshiel Sounds a bit like speculation - they could as well be agents of Sauron in employ of the Ringwraiths. Like those they encounter in Bree.

Comment: @Amarth: No, the guys in Bree were also in Saruman's employ, not Sauron's. Both these things are confirmed in the book. Ferny, the ringleader of the bad bunch in Bree in the beginning of the book, was literally Saruman's "big man" at the gate on the Brandywine in the Scouring chapters. Nobody was working for the Ringwraiths, they just terrified a few people.

Answer (score 39):

Essentially, Gandalf's mission was to help the Free Peoples defeat Sauron.  As far as he was concerned, it was no longer his place to interfere with things in Middle-Earth.  He was going to be returning to Valinor very shortly.  It was up to people to deal with their own problems now.  He did his part with Saruman in expelling him from the order.

> 'Deep in, but not at the bottom,' said Gandalf.  'You have forgotten Saruman.  He began to take an interest in the Shire before Mordor did.'
>
> 'Well, we've got you with us,' said Merry, 'so things will soon be cleared up'.
>
> 'I am with you at present' said Gandalf, 'but soon I shall not be.  I am not coming to the Shire.  You must settle its affairs yourselves; this is what you have been trained for.  Do you not yet understand?  My time is over: it is no longer my task to set things to right, nor to help folk to do so.  And as for you my dear friends, you will need no help.  You are grown up now.  Grown indeed very high; among the great you are, and I have no longer any fear at all for any of you.'
>
> Return of the King - Homeward Bound

Comment: How is Saruman "their own problems"? He is a Maia with some Maia powers.
The 4 hobbits are powerful enough to defeat him but the common hobbits of the Shire are not going to able to resist Saruman voice, what about all the suffering until they arrived?.
Did Gandalf just left the Shire open to Saruman to prove a point?

Comment: @OscarGarcia The Shire belongs to hobbiits, and shire problems are hobbit problems. They are now under the king again, so they could call on the king to send aid because one of his lands is under threat. In the end they didn’t need to. The point is that Gandalf’s work in middle earth is done, regardless of the nature of any problem. Remember it was men and hobbits and dwarves that killed Smaug. And hobbits that carried the ring into Mordor and destroyed it. Aside from taking out the Balrog and giving advice, Gandalf didn’t do much to help the ring bearers.

Comment: @OscarGarcia - keep in mind that Saruman wasn't [as powerful after leaving Orthanc](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68228/why-did-saruman-lose-his-power-after-he-was-banished-from-orthanc) ,

Comment: Good points. Also, note that the Valar had begun with large-scale meddling with Elves and Men and it Didn't End Well.  They concluded -- correctly or incorrectly -- that meddling was an error on their part and changed to a policy of non-involvement, leaving Men and Elves (who were entirely Iluvatar's creation) to Iluvatar.  Sending the Istari under strict limits and diminished power was their minimal intervention to counter the leftovers of Morgoth's own interventions.  Note also that Gandalf proved to be right that the Hobbits could easily handle things.

Comment: There's no indication at all that Saruman used his voice - or any powers - in the Shire.

Comment: If Shire problems are Hobbits problems you might as well have left Rohan on their own against Grima. Gandalf did not needed to intervene directly, he could have just told the Hobbits to do something and at the very least tell them to go the Shire instead of Rivendell

Comment: Grima wasn't just a Rohan problem, he was an agent of a still-in-power Saruman, and also was standing in the way in the fight against Sauron.  Getting rid of him was essential to the war effort.  Whereas stopping Sarumon from making a mess of the Shire isn't.

Comment: This is correct, but I think another key quote is (from Gandalf) "I was the Enemy of Sauron; and my work is finished." Sauron is 'dead' at this point and so Gandalf does not really have a 'license to intervene' any longer. Saruman was a factor in the war vs Sauron and Gandalf thus intervened then (similarly with his organizing the expedition against Smaug, since Smaug could have been used by Sauron, and his direct battle with the Balrog of Moria, who threatened the Ringbearer).

Comment: @OscarGarcia Also, re: Maia powers, Saruman clearly was reduced to the point where 'mortals' could deal with him without Gandalf's help. How he was weakened so far seems somewhat unclear, but his end makes it clear that he indeed *was* weakened thus.

Comment: @cometaryorbit Gandalf effectively delivers a "you're fired": 'Behold, I am not Gandalf the Grey, whom you betrayed. I am Gandalf the White, who has returned from death. You have no color now, and I cast you from your order and from the Council.' He raised his hand, and spoke in a clear cold voice. 'Saruman, your staff is broken.' (Two Towers, Book 1, Chapter 10)

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent yes, but that event is when Sauron is still a threat - Gandalf's task is not yet done, and Saruman as an enemy is clearly relevant to the war with Sauron. I read the "I was the Enemy of Sauron; and my work is finished" quote to mean that Gandalf's duty ended - and possibly his 'license to intervene in M-E' expired - at the destruction of the Ring/Sauron.

Comment: Could have at least prevented the Hobbits from going to Rivendell

Answer (score 4):

Is there any suggestion that Gandalf can see the future?  He explicitly says he ("the wise") can't.  He thinks Saruman can do "some mischief", but doesn't know what or where.  He clearly regards simply killing someone to prevent possible future problems as immoral, as evidenced by his conversation elsewhere:

> "Many that live deserve death. And some die that deserve life. Can you give it to them? Then be not too eager to deal out death in the name of justice, fearing for your own safety. Even the wise cannot see all ends."

PS: Another point that seems to have entirely been missed is that it wasn't Saruman's actions after that meeting that caused the problems in the Shire.  They'd been developing since Frodo & company left (and perhaps before), at the hands of Lotho Sackville-Baggins (AKA "The Chief") and collaborators like Ted Sandyman.  Saruman may have helped from afar, but it wasn't entirely his doing.  Having him go to the Shire at the end just provides a nice, neat finale.

Comment: GAndalf's quote is from"The Shadow of the Past" in The Fellowship of the Ring.

Comment: See my quotes, Saruman mentions the Shire and they did not needed to kill Saruman, just take him prisioner

Comment: Why take him prisoner? Who's going to watch him? Let him go to the Shire. He'll be there for a while, aiming for revenge. Easy to find, and the hobbits are seasoned warriors. Light work.

Comment: Elf's in Rivendell maybe? They were going there anyway.

Comment: @Oscar Garcia: Would the Elves have wanted him, and would they have kept him secure?  Remember what happened with Gollum?  Even in this world, keeping people imprisoned costs a significant amount of money.  There's also an ethical question with imprisoning people simply because they might do something bad in the future.

Comment: Gollum only escaped Mirkwood thanks to a diversionary orc attack, no such thing would happen again.

Comment: @Oscar Garcia: More accurate to say that Gollum took advantage of an Orc attack to escape.  Saruman, even in his much-diminished state, was much smarter & more competent than Gollum.  Guards ALWAYS become complacent and careless, and diversions ALWAYS happen, sooner or later.  If he was held in Rivendell, perhaps a flood or forest fire would provide one for Saruman to use.